# Firebird Consulta Select usando mesmo campo duas vezes

Tags: select, firebird

tenho um campo chamado paciente_id, quero criar um select +- assim

```
select count(paciente_id where = 0), count(paciente_id where <> 0) from agenda
```

não sei ficou claro, mas quero saber a quantidade de itens onde paciente_id é igual a zero e quando é diferente.

abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

segue a consulta que deve funcionar

```
SELECT (select count(paciente_id) from agenda where paciente_id='0') as id0, (select count(paciente_id) from agenda where paciente_id<>'0') as idok from agenda;
```

no result basta pegar sua var assim `$resultado['id0']` para id=0 e `$resultado['idok']` para `ids <> 0`

caso precise com data

```
SELECT (select count(paciente_id) from agenda where paciente_id='0' and dia_consulta='$data') as id0, (select count(paciente_id) from agenda where paciente_id<>'0' and dia_consulta='$data') as idok from agenda;
```

onde o dia_consulta vc troca pelo seu campo de data e a $data he sua data escolhida, OBs vc deve tratar a data de forma adequada para a consulta.

Comment: qual o formato de data q vc esta salvando ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um case:

```
select 

count(case when(paciente_id='0') then paciente_id else null end)  as id0

, count(case when(paciente_id<>'0') then paciente_id else null end) as idok

from agenda`
```